# Downgrade windows phone version 8.1 to 5 ~ 6.5

Tags: windows-phone, downgrade

I wonder if there is a way to downgrade my windows phone version 8.1 to 5 ~ 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Windows Phone 8.1 only can be downgraded to Windows Phone 8.0 in certain devices (Lumia 820, 920...).

Windows 5 ~ 6.5 have Windows Mobile that isn't compatible with Windows Phone.